# Dockerfile fail to build for FROM orsolin/php:5.3-apache

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm trying to build for legacy php5.3 inside my windows WSL2 ubuntu via latest docker desktop,

https://hub.docker.com/r/orsolin/docker-php-5.3-apache

The file content I put it this way

```
FROM orsolin/php:5.3-apache

RUN echo "ServerName localhost" >> /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y \
    git \
    zip \
    curl \
    sudo \
    unzip \
    libicu-dev \
    libbz2-dev \
    libpng-dev \
    libjpeg-dev \
    libmcrypt-dev \
    libreadline-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    g++

RUN docker-php-ext-install \
    bz2 \
    intl \
    bcmath \
    opcache \
    calendar \
    pdo_mysql \
    mysqli

COPY docker/apache/000-default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

RUN a2enmod rewrite headers

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
RUN mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/composer
RUN composer self-update

ARG uid
RUN useradd -G www-data,root -u $uid -d /home/devuser devuser
RUN mkdir -p /home/devuser/.composer && \
    chown -R devuser:devuser /home/devuser

EXPOSE 80
```

It come out with such error, not sure why...

```
 => ERROR [internal] load metadata for docker.io/orsolin/php:5.3-apache                                                                                            3.3s
 => [auth] orsolin/php:pull token for registry-1.docker.io                                                                                                         0.0s
------
 > [internal] load metadata for docker.io/orsolin/php:5.3-apache:
------
failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to create LLB definition: pull access denied, repository does not exist or may require authorization: server message: insufficient_scope: authorization failed
ERROR: Service 'web' failed to build : Build failed
```

Comment: Is that your complete Dockerfile? It's possible for the error to occur from misnamed multi-stage builds:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66507606/dockerfile-build-raising-insufficient-scope-authorization-failed-with-public-op

Comment: looks like not from this issue, i pasted in full code for reference

Comment: authorization issue; just use FROM koder/apache-php-5.3 ; this can build successfully but you might have to fiddle around w the extra build commands you have

Comment: And if you do `FROM orsolin/docker-php-5.3-apache` instead? There obviously isn't a `orsolin/php` so maybe just a miss in their documentation.

Comment: https://hub.docker.com/r/orsolin/docker-php-5.3-apache/tags?page=1&ordering=last_updated it does exists just permission issues ;

Comment: `orsolin/php` does not exist. (Check again what repo OP is trying to use.)

Comment: that's weird, I thought orsolin exist too, seeing stats showing Pulls 10K+  and see the 179.38MB file there. Anyway, not expert in docker, not sure how to identify real existence..